# Ocultar primeros 12 caracteres de EditCard para tarjeta de crédito android studio

Tags: android, edittext

Buenos días! Tengo una duda con android, y es que no puedo ocultar los primeros 12 caracteres de un campo EditCard (Usando: https://github.com/Morxander/EditCard) en android, necesito que solo los primeros 12 caracteres de una tarjeta de crédito se oculten, ¿cómo lo puedo hacer? Saludos y gracias de antemano!

Comment: Una vez guardada la tarjeta quieres que no se vea?

Comment: ya lo solucione, por si alguien también requiere, en este enlace esta la solución: https://github.com/dbachelder/CreditCardEntry gracias lois6b!!!

Comment: puedes publicarlo como respuesta (elaborada) y aceptartela a ti mismo.